# strで羅列された文字を辞書型に変換したい

Tags: python

str型で以下のような文字列を辞書型に変換しようと試行錯誤しております。
時間ばかり過ぎてしまいどうにもこうにも行かず質問させて頂きました。

何卒よろしくお願い致します。

辞書に変換したいstr

```
d = "Extension=4321,Type=1211,Port=S00091,Name=modori,Path_1=,"
```

作成したい辞書のイメージ

```
{"Extension":4321,"Type":1211,"Port":"S00091","Name":"modori","Path_1":null,}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`null` は文字列にしています。また、数値は全て整数であるとしています。

```py
def to_int(val_str):
    if not val_str:
        return 'null'
    try:
        i = int(val_str)
    except ValueError:
        i = val_str
    return i

d = "Extension=4321,Type=1211,Port=S00091,Name=modori,Path_1=,"
dic = {k: to_int(v) for k, v in [i.split('=') for i in d.split(',') if i]}
print(dic)

#
{'Extension': 4321, 'Type': 1211, 'Port': 'S00091', 'Name': 'modori', 'Path_1': 'null'}
```

Comment: 早速のご回答誠にありがとうございます。確認させて頂きます！！

Comment: ありがとうございました。抽出することが出来ました。すごすぎます。。自分も少しでも@metropolis様に近づけるように精進致します。